# Create a JSON serialized object to make a $.postJSON call

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a HTML form with several text input fields. The submitted data will be sent to a backend system with AJAX / JSON.
In jQuery, I do this, which works fine:

```
$("#addPerson").submit(function() {
    var person = $(this).serializeObject();
    $.postJSON("person/add/", person, function(data) {
        ...
    });
});
```

Now I have the problem, that I do not have a form, but I also want to add a person.
I have the values: `firstname = Tim`, `lastname = Smith`, `address = a street with number`, ...

But how can I create the key-value pairs, so I have the same like the line `var person = $(this).serializeObject();` submitted by a form and I can make a call with `$.postJSON`?

Thank you in advance & Best Regards, Tim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json object would look like this...  I think this is what you're looking for.

```
var first,
    last,
    addr;
var jsonObj = {
   firstname: first,
   lastname: last,
   address: addr
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the jQuery param function: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

```
$.param(object);
```

or the serialize function: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

```
$(jQuery_Collection).serialze()
```

But, I believe you can simply pass the object instead of the string, and jQuery will do it for you.