# Javascript Objects & arrays to server through form (json/??) - best practices

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I would like to know what would be the best practice to perform this:

1. Based on a selection, create a list of "selected items" which would be a list of this kind:

   ```
    {items

     {categoryString {tag_id1 {[fr]=>itemFR, [en]=>itemEN} 

     {categoryString {tag_id2 {[fr]=>item2FR, [en]=>item2EN}

     {categoryString2 {tag_id3 {[fr]=>item3FR, [en]=>item3EN} 

   }
   ```
2. Send this information to my server script when sending my form (not through javascript but normal post form).
3. Parse the received information on my server script (PHP).

**Point 1** is done like this:

```
function initTagArray(listSelector) {
    var et_tag_list = new Object();
    var cat = "CATDEF";
    et_tag_list[cat] = new Object();

    listSelector.each(function() {
        et_tag_list[cat][$(this).val()] = [];
        et_tag_list[cat][$(this).val()]['fr'] = [$(this).text()];
        et_tag_list[cat][$(this).val()]['en'] = [$(this).text()];
    });

    return et_tag_list;
}​
```

**Point 2**: I was thinking about storing that information in JSON array, but not sure how... By parsing my object/array and manually creating the json array?

**Point 3**: If Json array is sent it will be easy to parse it.

I'm looking here for the best practices on how to do this the most clean way as possible.

Comment: "Best practice" is a relative term. And your `et_tag_list` is of the form of a complex JSON object, not "a JSON array". This is a JSON array: `var json_arr = "['one','two','three']";`.

Comment: Break the functional requirements down into much more specific, individual tasks.

Comment: -Jared: true but my level 2 object contains an array.
-Tomalak: Not sure I can break this one in something more specific... It's already doing only one small functional job. And how would this help me solve my isse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use json stringified object/data that is either parsed as follows:

```
var myJSONObject = {"bindings": [
        {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "newURI", "regex": "^http://.*"},
        {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "deleteURI", "regex": "^delete.*"},
        {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "randomURI", "regex": "^random.*"}
    ]
}

var myJSONText = JSON.stringify(myJSONObject );
```

you can look for these links for implementation etc:
check question `text on this link`:  [json object accessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434487/json-object-accessing)
[JSON in JavaScript](http://www.json.org/js.html)
[JSON.Stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)
[pass json object to array - autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716262/pass-json-object-to-array-autocomplete)
[Create a JSON serialized object to make a $.postJSON call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563938/create-a-json-serialized-object-to-make-a-postjson-call)

Answer (score 0):

Try `JSON.stringify` on those objects. You will find lots of articles in the internet about how stringify works. For example try this: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON.

You can stringify complex JavaScript objects (say `x`) if you define `toJSON` function on it (probably you would implement in in such a way that it will gather `data` in the form of simple js dictionary and then you will call `JSON.stringify(data)` on it) and then call `JSON.stringify(x)`.